# evitar caché del navegador en angular

Tags: angular, angular8, cache

Tengo una aplicación en Angular, cuando la subo a producción, para visualizar la nueva versión
debo recargar hasta 2 veces.
Yo se que esto no es medio normal,
¿Hay alguien que me pueda guiar?
Solo hago esto.
Gracias!!

```
     ng build --prod --output-hashing=all
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes poner estas etiquetas en tu `head` para que el navegador no guarde la cache:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

> El encabezado HTTP Cache-Control especifica directivas (instrucciones) para almacenar temporalmente (caching) tanto en peticiones como en respuestas. Una directiva dada en una petición no significa que la misma directiva estar en la respuesta.
>
> Tomado de [Cache-Control-HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control)

Tomado de [aqui](http://cristian.sulea.net/blog/disable-browser-caching-with-meta-html-tags/).

Answer (score 2):

En realidad, `ng build --prod` debería producir archivos de extensión `.js` con nombres diferentes, evitando por completo problemas de cache. El único archivo que no se apega a esta regla y que por lo tanto podría causar problemas de cache sería `index.html`. Si ese es el problema, entonces debes encontrar cómo configurar tu servidor para que incluya encabezados de respuesta (response headers) que le indiquen al navegador que nunca guarde un cache de ese archivo.

Comment: @digitalandolé, depende del servidor que esté usando. Una vez que tenga esta información, sugeriría una busqueda en Google y si no encuentra nada, entonces haga una pregunta nueva en este espacio de es.stackoverflow.com.